# Notepad++: Insert at Line Start in Selection, Excluding Empty Lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

In a document, there are regions of sentences that need bulletpointing. So this:

> Blah blah blah.
>
> One!
>
> Two!
>
> Blah blah blah.

...becomes this:

> Blah blah blah.
>
> • One!
>
> • Two!
>
> Blah blah blah.

Is there a way in Notepad++ to insert bullet characters at the start of each line in a selection, but *exclude blank lines*?

Answer (score 1):

Select area you want

press `CTRL + H`, select `Regular Expression` and check `In Selection`

Find:

```
^.+$
```

Replace:

```
• $0
```

Comment: That inserts bullets on *all* lines. I wanted specifically to exclude empty lines. So to answer my own question: Do what you say, *then* replace ^• $ with nothing.

Comment: It doesn't include bullets on empty lines

Comment: It sounds like the "blank" line might not be compeletely blank, but contain spaces. In that case, try `^\w+$`, assuming that all of the lines that you want bulleted contain only Word (alphanumeric) characters.(Or `^\w+!$` if they all do end in '!') Or `^[^ \t]+$` to match lines that contain anything except spaces and/or tabs.